# How do i keep Akka Java actors alive on remote systems ready receive message-deployment?

Tags: java, akka, akka-remoting

I am trying to create AKKA actor clusters on distributed systems with JAVA.
I am able to use them in single machine.
Just wondering suppose I am keeping the actors in different machines, how do i keep them alive to be ready to receive message.

1.Should i be keeping them in a running server like netty?
 Could be like a Spring boot executable jar
2.Should i keep a public static void main alive  with threads or loop?

is there any full fledged example as well with deployment?

Comment: What do you mean by keeping it alive? Actors don't shut down if you don't do so programatically. About the other questions, you just need an ActorSystem running somewhere with the proper configuration, in the same way that you would run a single machine app. Akka nodes communicates through TCP or UDP so be sure to configure the infrastructure as well, you could start by running different JVM in your local machine though.